# Mounting a drive in google colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

My google colab notebook has been shared with other users and they can edit code written in the notebook.
My question is if I mount my drive to that notebook, will the drive be visible and accessible to me only or will it be visible to other editors too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drive content won't be linked with the notebook. For anyone viewing, they will have to sign into an account for them to mount a gdrive.